# Datepicker HTML5 scroll date

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML5 datepicker, how do we scroll the date dropdown up? At the moment, you can't scroll the date to go further back, you need to select a date (2009), then this brings up further options to go further back with the date.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" required="required">
```

Is there any ideas?

Comment: Hello, Χριστός Ανέστη!!!.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date

Comment: What you've shown is not a date input, is that a typo?

Comment: Can you see in this link Chris the external resources theyre using?

Comment: This is a HTML5 datepicker